# How to correctly get the values I want from Web REST GET from android app written in Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, rest, api

This is my API request:

```
http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=59.91;lon=10.76
```

I need to get 2 values from the above, namely the TEMPERATURE's "value" below location and time and I need SYMBOL's "number" below location and time. But for now I only try to get the temperature value.

I have followed different guides, but nothing is helping.

This what I have right now. Inside MainActivity I have:

```
private class TemperatureTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("time");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            Node node = nodelist.item(0);
            if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;

                testView.setText(testView.getText() + "\nTemperature: "
                + getNode("location", element));
            }
    }
}

private static String getNode(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node value = (Node) nodeList.item(0);
    return value.getNodeValue();
}
```

And then I called it with:

```
String apiUrl = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=59.91;lon=10.76";

new TemperatureTask().execute(apiUrl);
```

Anyways, I dont get any Exceptions but

```
+ getNode("location", element));
```

returns nothing.

What can I do to get the temperature? The reason this takes a lot of time for me is that most XML I see dont have this format with attributes with many values like this.